# An interesting picture in differential geometry from the book *Visual Differential geometry and Forms by Needham* is not clear for me.

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition

Can someone give me an intuition why $dx(v)=v^1$ is **perpendicular** to $x$ ?
The intuition should be given by [32.8], but not enough for me.

[image]

Comment: $x$ is a coordinate function, although perhaps he’s using $\mathbf x$ as a unit vector. Who knows. And $v^1$ is a scalar, not a vector. $dx(\mathbf v)$ gives the $x$-coordinate of $\mathbf v$.

Comment: @TedShifrin OK. But what he writes is this: **The above reasoning applies equally
well to $R^3$, in which case $dx$ is the family of unit-spaced planes perpendicular to the $x$-axis, as illustrated in [32.8].** I do not even know what is a **unit spaced plane** !

Comment: $dx=0$ gives parallel lines (planes) perpendicular to the axis. He’s using intuitive physical intuition such as one has in multivariable calculus with the flux of a vector field.

Comment: @TedShifrin "Flux" sounds familiar to me but not how is is using that notion. Could you be please more explicit ? He writes on the page 378: "Φ(v1, v2) ≡ Amount of fluid crossing P per unit time = flux of Ψ through P. " Is that relevant ?

Comment: Yes. That’s the 2-form associated to the vector field $\Psi$. You might check out my YouTube lectures on forms, line integrals, surface integrals, Stokes’s Theorem. I discuss flux in there. The link is in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ you have the concept of level surfaces:
For each $p$ in the range of $f$, the level set at $p$ is
$$S_p=f^{-1}(p)=\left\{v=(x,y,z)^{\top}\ :f(v)=p\right\}.$$
These $S_p$ regularly are surfaces.

An important case is when $f$ is linear, as
$$f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$$
because the level surfaces are the planes
$$ax+by+cz=p.$$

Now for the case of the 1-forms $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$ we have
$$dx(v)=x,$$
$$dy(v)=y,$$
and
$$dz(v)=z.$$

So the level sets (at $p$) of $dx$, say, is the plane $(p,y,z)^{\top}$.

For $dy$ is $(x,p,z)^{\top}$ and finally $(z,y,p)^{\top}$ for $dz$.